# asp.net timespan - 0.5 (half day)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timespan

I've been using the following timespan function to work out the number of days between two dates which works correctly.

```
    Dim dtStart As Date = txtHStart_Date.Text
    Dim dtEnd As Date = txtHEnd_Date.Text

    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dtEnd - dtStart  

    txtNoofDays.Text = ts.TotalDays.ToString()

    Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays)
```

I've now tried to add a check box (as a half day selection). If the check box is selected I want it to minus 0.5 off the total days. But i'm getting the blue line telling me its an error on "ts = (dtEnd - dtStart) - 0.5"

```
    Dim dtStart As Date = txtHStart_Date.Text
    Dim dtEnd As Date = txtHEnd_Date.Text


    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dtEnd - dtStart


    For Each li As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
        If li.Value = "Half Day" Then
        ts = (dtEnd - dtStart) - 0.5
    Else
            ts = dtEnd - dtStart
     End If

    Next
    txtNoofDays.Text = ts.TotalDays.ToString()

    Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays)
```

Any suggestions on how to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ts` is your `TimeSpan` value. You can't subtract 0.5 from a `TimeSpan` - I know what you want it to mean in this case, but why would "days" be the right unit by default? You can subtract 0.5 days explicitly though:

```
ts = (dtEnd - dtStart) - TimeSpan.FromDays(0.5)
```

It's not clear why you're iterating over *all* the items but only actually *using* the last item, by the way. If your plan was actually to use the number of days for each item, I'd be tempted to do the subtraction after working out the number of days:

```
Dim days = (dtEnd - dtStart).TotalDays
If li.Value = "Half Day" Then
    days = days - 0.5
End If

' Use days here
```